# Unknown compiler flag/parameter to cpp

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-flags

I'm working through the tutorial of [pybind11](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#creating-bindings-for-a-simple-function). To compile an example, I'm supposed to use the following line:

```
c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -I <path-to-pybind11>/include `python-config --cflags --ldflags` example.cpp -o example.so
```

I do not understand the part

```
`python-config --cflags --ldflags`
```

It's not primarily about its content, it's more about: What meaning does it have in the compile command? Does it belong to the `-I` flag? What's with those "`" ?

I checked the manual of c++/cpp, but didn't find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The backquotes

When in shell commands you see stuff between backquotes ``, it means that it's a separate command that is run before the main one and whatever it writes to standard output is used in the main command.

For example:

```
rm `cat file_to_delete.txt`
```

Consider `file_to_delete.txt` contains "sausage.png"
The `cat file_to_delete.txt` part is run first and outputs "sausage.png"
This is then inserted into the main command as follows:

```
rm sausage.png
```

#### What your example does

So in your example, `python-config --cflags --ldflags` is a separate command from `c++` and whatever it outputs is replaced in the original command. If it outputs `-Wall -Wextra -lmath` your `c++` command will end up like this:

```
c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -I <path-to-pybind11>/include -Wall -Wextra -lmath example.cpp -o example.so
```

#### Conclusion

The point of the `python-config` command is thus to provide the flags `gcc` (`c++` actually uses `gcc`) will need to run your C++ code with your python code.

Answer (score 4):

What

```
 `python-config --cflags --ldflags`
```

does is execute the command "python-config --cflags --ldflags" and replace the output (i.e. extra arguments to your compilation command).

The program `python-config` provides the necessary build options for your code. 
From `python-config` documentation:

> python-config - output build options for python C/C++
>   extensions or embedding
>
> --cflags
>
> print the C compiler flags.
>
> --ldflags
>
> print the flags that should be passed to the linker.

Providing such a tool is a common approach so that the necessary build options on a particular is system is automatically found, which would otherwise require the users to figure out themselves.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, `python-config --cflags --ldflag` produces:

> -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
>   -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions

So, it's equivalent to doing this myself:

> c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -I /include
>   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
>   -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions example.cpp -o example.so

Now you can see, why the helper program is handy (it figures out what libraries are needed and where they are located etc).

---

On a relevant note, I prefer `$(python-config --cflags --ldflags)` instead of `python-config --cflags --ldflags` as the `$(..)` is recommended over backticks by POSIX. You can see the [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) here under section "Command Substitution".